# Oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am dealing with tables which (for the purposes of displaying here) look like the following:

A

```
A_ID         | Clob_Col   
1            | value        
2            | value   
3            | null   
4            | value   
5            | null  
6            | value   
7            | value   
8            | null  
9            | value   
10           | value
```

B

```
B_ID          |A_ID          | C_ID  
10            | 1            | 20  
11            | 2            | 20  
12            | 6            | 21  
13            | 7            | 22  
14            | 8            | 22  
15            | 9            | 23
```

C

```
C_ID       
20                  
21               
22               
23                    
24                   
25
```

(All tables have more columns)

I wish to write a query which will return values from all three tables but exclude records where certain values match those in Table C  (NOT IN).
My problem is to return the values from Table A which *do not* link to Table B when using a NOT IN clause on Table C.

Example:

```
SELECT a.A_ID, a.Clob_Col, b.B_ID, c.C_ID
from A a
LEFT JOIN B b on a.A_ID=b.A_ID
LEFT JOIN C c on b.C_ID=c.C_ID
WHERE a.AID >= 2
AND a.AID <= 7
AND c.C_ID NOT IN (22, 23, 24)
```

The last line - `c.C_ID NOT IN (22, 23, 24)` - will leave us with the following records in the B table:  b_BID = 10,11 or 12

In turn, these link to the following records in Table A: a.ID = 1,2 and 6.

The first clause - `a.AID >= 2 AND a.AID <= 7` - further restricts our final result to  a.ID = 2 and 6.
The final result will look like:

```
A_ID         |Clob_Col         |B_ID          |C_ID         
2            |value            |11            |20                   
6            |value            |12            |21
```

**But** I also want to return the A table records which don't link to Table B - a.ID 3, 4 and 5
So I expect my results to be

```
A_ID         |Clob_Col       |B_ID        |C_ID       
2            |value          |11          |20       
3            |null           |null        |null       
4            |value          |null        |null      
5            |null           |null        |null                 
6            |value          |12          |21
```

Note: The reason I included the Clob value is that someone suggested selecting all records and then performing a MINUS operation on the records where `c.C_ID IN (22, 23, 24)`.

This seemed reasonable however Oracle does not allow MINUS operation where Clob columns are involved.

Comment: Just a glimpse, but don't you need some ON clause after the JOINs?

Comment: a fiddle of this data would be most useful

Comment: Regarding joining the c table - if the c_id value for a_id = 6 in the b table was a value not in the c_id table, what would you want the final output to display? Would the a_id = 6 row be displayed or not? (in short, I'm asking if the c table should be inner or outer joined to the b table, and if outer joined, whether you want nulls to be counted as not being in (22,23,24) or not)

Comment: Thank you every one for noticing the missing ON s.
This was an omission which has been rectified.
It doesn't address the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're after:

```
with a as (select 1 a_id, 'val1' clob_col from dual union all
           select 2 a_id, 'val2' clob_col from dual union all
           select 3 a_id, null clob_col from dual union all
           select 4 a_id, 'val4' clob_col from dual union all
           select 5 a_id, null clob_col from dual union all
           select 6 a_id, 'val6' clob_col from dual union all
           select 7 a_id, 'val7' clob_col from dual union all
           select 8 a_id, null clob_col from dual union all
           select 9 a_id, 'val9' clob_col from dual union all
           select 10 a_id, 'val10' clob_col from dual),
     b as (select 10 b_id, 1 a_id, 20 c_id from dual union all
           select 11 b_id, 2 a_id, 20 c_id from dual union all
           select 12 b_id, 6 a_id, 21 c_id from dual union all
           select 13 b_id, 7 a_id, 22 c_id from dual union all
           select 14 b_id, 8 a_id, 22 c_id from dual union all
           select 15 b_id, 9 a_id, 23 c_id from dual),
     c as (select 20 c_id from dual union all
           select 21 c_id from dual union all
           select 22 c_id from dual union all
           select 23 c_id from dual union all
           select 24 c_id from dual union all
           select 25 c_id from dual)
select a.a_id, a.clob_col, b.b_id, c.c_id
from   a
       left outer join b on (a.a_id = b.a_id)
       left outer join c on (b.c_id = c.c_id)
where  a.a_id between 2 and 7
and    (c.c_id not in (22, 23, 24) or c.c_id is null)
order by a.a_id;

      A_ID CLOB_COL       B_ID       C_ID
---------- -------- ---------- ----------
         2 val2             11         20
         3                               
         4 val4                          
         5                               
         6 val6             12         21


and if c_id is 27 for a_id = 6 in the b table:

      A_ID CLOB_COL       B_ID       C_ID
---------- -------- ---------- ----------
         2 val2             11         20
         3                               
         4 val4                          
         5                               
         6 val6             12
```

You have to take account of the fact that c_id could be null, as well as not being in the set of values being excluded.

ETA: Thanks to Ponder Stibbons' suggestion in the comments, if you didn't want the row to be displayed where a.a_id = b.a_id matches but there isn't a match on b.c_id = c.c_id, then changing the `or c.c_id is null` to `or b.c_id is null` removes that row:

```
with a as (select 1 a_id, 'val1' clob_col from dual union all
           select 2 a_id, 'val2' clob_col from dual union all
           select 3 a_id, null clob_col from dual union all
           select 4 a_id, 'val4' clob_col from dual union all
           select 5 a_id, null clob_col from dual union all
           select 6 a_id, 'val6' clob_col from dual union all
           select 7 a_id, 'val7' clob_col from dual union all
           select 8 a_id, null clob_col from dual union all
           select 9 a_id, 'val9' clob_col from dual union all
           select 10 a_id, 'val10' clob_col from dual),
     b as (select 10 b_id, 1 a_id, 20 c_id from dual union all
           select 11 b_id, 2 a_id, 20 c_id from dual union all
           select 12 b_id, 6 a_id, 27 c_id from dual union all
           select 13 b_id, 7 a_id, 22 c_id from dual union all
           select 14 b_id, 8 a_id, 22 c_id from dual union all
           select 15 b_id, 9 a_id, 23 c_id from dual),
     c as (select 20 c_id from dual union all
           select 21 c_id from dual union all
           select 22 c_id from dual union all
           select 23 c_id from dual union all
           select 24 c_id from dual union all
           select 25 c_id from dual)
select a.a_id, a.clob_col, b.b_id, c.c_id
from   a
       left outer join b on (a.a_id = b.a_id)
       left outer join c on (b.c_id = c.c_id)
where  a.a_id between 2 and 7
and    (c.c_id not in (22, 23, 24) or b.c_id is null)
order by a.a_id;
```

Comment: I think that this is best answer, the only thing is: _I also want to return the A table records which don't link to Table B_. 
The difference is small - `b.b_id is null` instead of `c.c_id is null` - it's visible if we insert into B (16, 4, 55).

Comment: @PonderStibbons I'm not sure I get you - (16, 4, 55) does mean that A is linked to B based on a_id = 4? My query gives an output of (4, val4, 16, null) - what were you thinking it should return?

Comment: @PonderStibbons hmm, I see what you mean - it's whether or not the OP wants the row returned if there's no match on `c.c_id = b.c_id` when `a.b_id = b.b_id`. I was trying to get that clarified in my comment on the question, although I'm not sure if I made myself clear enough up there!

Comment: @PonderStibbons updated my answer with your suggestion - thanks. I was scratching my head a bit as to how you'd exclude that row if you didn't want it showing! All credit to you for that *{:-)

Comment: Many thanks for answering the question asked.
Works a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to use "on" clause for join. You can try this :

```
SELECT a.A_ID, a.Clob_Col, b.B_ID, c.C_ID
from A a
LEFT JOIN B b on a.A_ID=b.A_ID
LEFT JOIN C c on b.C_ID=c.C_ID
WHERE a.A_ID between 2 and 7
AND c.C_ID NOT IN (22, 23, 24)
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Once again thank you every one for noticing the missing ON s.
This was an omission which has been rectified.
It doesn't address the question though.

Answer (score 2):

Include what your joining on and also you can use `BETWEEN` for the first WHERE clause.

Also i would use INNER JOINS rather then LEFT as per your data.

```
SELECT a.A_ID, a.Clob_Col, b.B_ID, c.C_ID
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b ON a.A_ID = b.B_ID
INNER JOIN C c ON b.C_ID = c.C_ID
WHERE a.AID BETWEEN 2 AND 7
AND c.C_ID NOT IN (22, 23, 24)
```

Comment: Not addressing question. Still provides same result